# FFMPEG - Screen capture with mic and speaker audios

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, recording

I am trying to record and stream the screen along with audio from microphone and speakers. So far, I am able to record from either the microphone or the speaker, with the following codes.

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 7.5 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Microphone Array (Realtek High Definition Audio)"  -b:a 64k -f mpegts -t 60 - | ffmpeg  -f mpegts -i - -c copy  -f mpegts udp://192.168.0.242:1234?pkt_size=1316  -c  copy  -b 400k TestFFmpegPy.mkv
```

Need to record the audio from speaker also, along with mic audio.

```
audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)"
```

How to record both audio streams together.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
> ffmpeg -video_size 1600x900 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :0.0 \
    -f pulse -thread_queue_size 512k -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo \
    -f pulse -thread_queue_size 512k -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor  \
     -filter_complex "[1:a:0][2:a:0]amix=2[aout]" -map 0:V:0 -map "[aout]" ${OUTPUT}.mkv
```

To determine our `input` and `output` we can use:

```
> pacmd list-sources | perl -lne '/(?<=name: <)alsa[^>]+/ && print $&'
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
```

And this part:

```
-filter_complex "[1:a:0][2:a:0]amix=2[aout]" -map 0:V:0 -map "[aout]"
```

is about Concatenation [1](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate), [2](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map). Also it is a quick and dirty one, you may need to change some options.